# EF Core - Filtering by a child collection of Key Value pairs extremely slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

My main system entity is 'tagged' with a child collection of key value pairs, which I want to use to filter a listing of the main entities. However, the EF core query I've written below is far too slow for acceptable use.

**Simplified Entity Classes**

```
 public class MainEntity
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public string Stuff {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
 }

 public class Tag
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int MainEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual MainEntity MainEntity { get; set; }
 }
```

**Simplified Query**

```
//filter params passed into the query function
//String? stuffFilter
//List<Tag> tagSearchValues

var query = _dbContext.MainEntities.Where(
    me => ((!stuffFilter.HasValue || me.Stuff == stuffFilter.Value)                    
    && (tagSearchValues == null || tagSearchValues.Count == 0 ||
    (
    (me.Tags.Select(t => t.Key).Any(tk => tagSearchValues.Select(s => s.Key).Any(sk => sk == tk))) &&
    (me.Tags.Select(t => t.Value).Any(tv => tagSearchValues.Select(s => s.Value).Any(sv => sv == tv)))
    )
    ).                    
    OrderByDescending(l => me.Created).AsNoTracking();
```

I'm a bit rusty with EF (and using EF Core for the first time), but the problem is down to the way I'm filtering by the child Tag collection with the multiple .Any() commands (the query performs perfectly when no Tag filters are specified).

I can't think of a another way to filter the child Tag object collection against the selected Tag filter objects - a single filter Tag would be much simpler, and quicker, I imagine.

The only alternative I can currently think of is to do a custom SQL query myself, but it seems a shame to resort to that already when putting together my first EF Core query!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your proposed query can't be evaluated fully as SQL because there's no SQL equivalent for a collection containing non-primitive values, `tagSearchValues`. This causes EF to auto-switch to [client-side evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). That is, it pulls into memory all entities that meet the `stuffFilter` condition and all of their tags, and then it applies the tags predicate. That, evidently, is not efficient.

Secondly, the query is inaccurate. Entities containing tags with certain keys *and* tags with certain values isn't the same as tags containing specific key/value *combinations*. It requires a query that matches each combination, like this:

```
db.MainEntities.Where(...)
    .Where(m => tagSearchValues
       .Any(t => m.Tags.Any(mt => mt.Key == t.Key 
                               && mt.Value == t.Value)))
```

However, if you do that, EF will again turn to inefficient client-side evaluation and you'd even have to apply `Include` or lazy loading yourself to pull the tags into memory. (Moreover, for some reason, EF fires tons of redundant queries).

Fact of the matter is that EF (like other ORMs) isn't well-geared to such pair-wise comparisons server-side. Therefore you need a predicate builder to build the tag predicates. There are several predicate buiders, f.e. in [Linqkit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). I use [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) because it's nice and simple. The recipe is: build a predicate and apply it in a `Where()`:

```
var tagPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MainEntity>();
if (tagSearchValues.Any())
{
    tagPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MainEntity>();
    foreach (var tag in tagSearchValues)
    {
        tagPredicate = tagPredicate.Or(m => m.Tags
                           .Any(t => t.Key == tag.Key
                                  && t.Value == tag.Value));
    }
}

var query = _dbContext.MainEntities
    .Where(m => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stuff) || m.Stuff == stuff)
    .Where(tagPredicate);
... // Use query
```

I use `Or` because I assume (from your query) that you want entities having *any* tag in the search tags. That's why I start with a `PredicateBuilder.True` predicate, so the query will return results if there are no search tags, similar to your original query.

Comment: Gert, thank you 1000 times for the education on EF, spotting the error in my Tag value and key checks, and for providing the perfect, simple solution. I've only ever used EF in relatively simple use cases, so hadn't come across predicates before, but as you suggested, it has prevented the dozens of select queries that EF Core was unnecessarily performing, to look up Tag entities one by one. You've made this system come alive, and saved me from all the work required to replace the EF Core look up with custom SQL - you're a top human being!

Comment: Gert fully deserves it! He's the one who inspired me to start digging into EF depts.

Comment: Just a note that EF Core 3.x and newer do not silently switch to client execution or issue multiple SQL calls.  Instead, they throw an exception if server side execution is not possible, or you can explicitly switch to client side execution by use of AsEnumerable() or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what SQL is being generated by EF Core `Any`? EF Core has the unfortunate design property of silently executing queries on the client side if they can't be translated to SQL.

What if you consolidate the `Key` and `Value` testing?

```
(me.Tags.Any(met => tagSearchValues.Any(st => st.Tag == met.Tag && st.Value == met.Value)))
```

Or what if you use `Contains` instead?

```
(me.Tags.Select(t => t.Key).Any(tk => tagSearchValues.Select(s => s.Key).Contains(tk))) &&
(me.Tags.Select(t => t.Value).Any(tv => tagSearchValues.Select(s => s.Value).Contains(tv)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @NetMage I had a good play around with several attempts at speeding up the query based on your suggestions, but couldn't get EF Core to stop performing the dozens of redundant queries that were causing the problem.

Comment: If EF Core is performing dozens of extra queries, that means it is not able to translate some part of the query to SQL and send it. How many elements are in the `tagSearchValues` list?

Comment: Just a note that EF Core 3.x and newer do not silently switch to client execution or issue multiple SQL calls.  Instead, they throw an exception if server side execution is not possible, or you can explicitly switch to client side execution by use of AsEnumerable() or similar.

Comment: @Matt I know - but this was written in 2018.